# ActionScript Encapsulating a Static Function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, static

i would simply like to encapsulate a function in it's own .as file, but i can't quite get it.

```
package
{
public class NumberAdd
    {
    public function NumberAdd()
        {
        public static function myNumber(val:Number):Number
            {
            return val + 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this i would call it like this:

```
var myNum:Number = NumberAdd.myNumber(2);
trace(myNum); //traces 4
```

what is my mistake?

Comment: move the method out of the constructor and you should be fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package
{
    public class NumberAdd
    {
       public static function myNumber(val:Number):Number
       {
           return val + 2;
       }
    }
}
```

try this